# context not calling performblock

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g021ae486d8d8acb3999343609097fcba7f7befa53

this is the link to an assignment app which i got for my homework it most of its concepts taken from the stanford cs193p course as iam studing that too, this app has 3 modules 
1 camera
2 map
3 contacts

the camera and map modules are working fine not as hoped but fine cut in the contacts module I
am using core data model to store contacts from contacts directory which you'll see when you run the app.

Now the problem is that my view adds the contacts to the core data but they are not showing in the table so when i tried to debug the application i saw that the method
[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{}];

is not calling the block of code inside it thats why the data is not even getting saved in the data model let alone show in table.

very very thanks in advance...

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Demo Document"];
UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
    [document saveToURL:url
       forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
      completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
          if (success) {
              self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
          }
      }];
} else if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
    [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
        }
    }];
} else {
    self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
}
if(self.managedObjectContext==nil)
    NSLog(@"nil object");
```

Comment: Check if `self.managedObjectContext` is `nil`.

Comment: yes it is nil i just checked but how can it be nil i've initialized itwith document's managed object context

Comment: can you take a look at the project and help me out?

Comment: You really should try to debug the problem yourself. Set a breakpoint where you think the context should be set, see if that code is executed and so on ...

Comment: the sqlite file is not being created on the disc wait ill post the code i'm using to create the file on disc

Comment: the code i,ve just posted is not creating sqlite file on disc and log is returning nil object

Comment: AssignmentAppModel.xcdatamodeld is the name of my data model

Comment: Lookup the documentation of `saveToURL:...` and `openWithCompletionHandler:`. That are *asynchronous* methods. `self.managedObjectContext` is set later, when the completion block is called.

Comment: i checked the document directory in ifile and there is a folder Demo Document inside  the documents folder and another storecontent folder in Demo Document then inside there is a file named persistantstore shouldn't there be a sqlite file?